# How do I set a button to two different commands?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need the button to change both the background of the main window and the secondary window (called label). I have seen ways to make buttons do 2 different commands, however, I have not seen ways to make a button do two different commands while the command has a variable in the parentheses after the command. Ex. "def command(abc)" <---- here. code below

```
def color_press(col):
    window.configure(bg='#'+col)
    

def color_pressLAB(labelcol):
    window.configure(bg='#'+labelcol)
```

and then the button code is:

```
yellowButton = Button(frame, text='yellow', height=2, width=5, font=25, background='#F5E1A2',
                      command=lambda: color_press('F5E1A2'),
                      command=lambda: color_pressLAB('FFFFBF')
```

I have only been able to make them change to the same color, but I want the windows to be different colors.

Comment: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-bind-multiple-commands-to-tkinter-button/)
Have you tired something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description:

The answer is very simple you just have to make use of multiple function usability of lambda in your code. But the way you are using is incorrect instead try this.

### Solution:

```py
def color_press(col):
    window.configure(bg='#'+col)
    
def color_pressLAB(labelcol):
    window.configure(bg='#'+labelcol)

yellowButton = Button(frame, text='yellow', height=2, width=5, font=25, background='#F5E1A2',
                      command=lambda: (color_press('F5E1A2'),color_pressLAB('FFFFBF'))
```

Comment: I think this makes the code harder to debug than if you created a special purpose function that calls the other two functions.

Comment: I think that its good but you are right in big codes its kinda hard to trace where the error is being originated from

Answer (score 1):

Changing color of two widgets can be written inside the same function. But since you want to trigger two functions with the same button, I'm splitting into two. So, this idea will be useful to you in a situation where you really need to trigger two functions simultaneousely.

```
def color_press():
    window.configure(bg='#F5E1A2')
    

def color_pressLAB():

    #Call the first function here
    color_press()

    #As the name of the second window is label
    label.configure(bg='#FFFFBF')
    
    
#map only the second function with the button
yellowButton = Button(frame, text='yellow', height=2, width=5, font=25, background='#F5E1A2',command = color_pressLAB)
```

Comment: It losts the flexibility of using multiple buttons to set different sets of colors.

Comment: @acw1668, If that is the problem, declare configuration of label as a separate function. And declare different functions of each and every combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the two functions and call them when a button is clicked, it is better to create another new function that call them and associate that new function to the button:

```py
...

def color_press(col):
    # change background color of main window
    window.configure(bg='#'+col)

def color_pressLAB(labelcol):
    # change background color of secondary window
    label.configure(bg='#'+labelcol)

def change_color(col, labelcol):
    color_press(col)
    color_pressLAB(labelcol)

...

yellowButton = Button(frame, text="yellow", height=2, width=6,
                      font=('',25), bg="#F5E1A2",
                      command=lambda: change_color("F5E1A2", "FFFFBF"))

...
```